# Convertir hora en SQL Server con el formato: 19/07/2017 11:00:00 a. m

Tags: sql

tengo el siguiente script para insertar en la base :

```
INSERT INTO k_horario(OIDHorario, OIDEmpleado, OIDSalon, OIDTaller, Hora, Dia, Semana, Duracion, FechaCreacion) VALUES ('3de7d494-5de9-4ab5-8d30-816103f1a9a0', '396983d6-63bd-4a0d-82fa-fb2fdac90a6e', 'a574f65e-0e81-46ed-9a91-3d40302a6319', '6958a0d9-90e8-4e09-9196-a3523edc9589', '17/07/2017 06:00:00 a. m.', 1, 29, 60, '14/07/2017 09:42:31 a. m.')
```

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto me lanza el siguiente error:

**Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.**

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Es decir, ¿quieres introducir los datos así:  `14/07/2017 09:42:31 a. m.` en la base de datos? Si la respuesta es sí, no me parece una buena idea guardar datos formateados en la BD. Si luego los necesitas en otro formato se te hará muy complicado.

Answer (score 1):

Si ejecutas esto

```
select ISDATE('17/07/2017 06:00:00 a. m.')
```

Vas a darte cuenta que no es un formato válido de fecha, por tanto usa un formato ISO como el siguiente:

```
select ISDATE('20170717 06:00:00')
select ISDATE('20170717 16:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu tabla tienes problema en lo que es la hora y la fecha

Para la hora

```
select convert(datetime, RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING('17/07/2017 06:00:00 am', 11, 20))))
```

Para la fecha

```
select convert(datetime, RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING('17/07/2017 06:00:00 am', 1, 10))))
```